# Recommendation solution for Magento Community edition

Tags: magento2

It's my first time discovering Magento so please forgive me if the question is kind of stupid,

My client wants to go with Magento Community version and wants to have a recommendation system as a part of the shop,

I've discovered that recommendation functionality is something shipped with Magento Commerce,

But I'm wondering is there any free open source alternatives that could be used with Magento Community version?

Thanks, Cheers

Comment: What kind? Like other people also brought this?

Comment: @MarkRees exactly

Comment: Most aren't free. The best I've used is the amasty one. https://amasty.com/magento-2-customers-also-bought.html